# 'Closing' (hiding) terminal without clearing it

Tags: unity, command-line, personalization

So I'm using always on top and on active workspace with transparent background (you see where it's going), and I'd like to be able to just close terminal, and next time I open it to resume work.

e.G. let's say I'm using nano, I close terminal and next time I open it, nano's still open and I keep doing other things.

Is it even possible or tabbing / minimizing is the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try drop down terminals like [Tilda](https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda) or [Guake](https://github.com/Guake/guake).

Personally, I always have 2 drop down terminals running.

Comment: using yakuake, multiple instances :D